# DNS resolver is not working for a my domain name

Tags: google-chrome, dns, domains

I have a problem when I'm trying to access my website by the domain name. It's a free domain name from [Freenom](https://my.freenom.com/clientarea.php). (kesaralive.ml) It shows this error **DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN** in google chrome. when I'm trying to use the ping command. It shows this error.
Error: *`Temporary failure in name resolution`*.
[temporary failure error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJUOM.png).
I even tried using `nslookup` command.
and It says '`server can't find kesaralive.ml :SERVFAIL`'
[server can't find error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sk42L.png).

I tried all these [steps](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/dns_probe_finished_nxdomain/#dns-domain). but It didn't work for me. After I tried several times I changed my DNS address to the [80.80.80.80](http://www.freenom.world/en/index.html?lang=en). and It's working when It's 80.80.80.80 but the thing is others can't access the domain name by using their computer unless they change their DNS address. I want to know how to fix this issue.

Comment: I can get to it.  (It redirects to your GitHub page)  Perhaps for whoever your internet provider is, they are having their own DNS issues .....?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue for the past few hours. Its registered with freenom and I am using cloudflare nameservers.

Comment: Yes, it redirects to my GitHub page. I can access it when my DNS address is 80.80.80.80 but my friends can't access it by using my domain name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://dnsviz.net/d/kesaralive.ml/YdfV0Q/dnssec/ and the big ERROR box:

> ml zone: The server(s) were not responsive to queries over UDP. (185.21.168.1, 2a04:1b00::1)

You can not fix anything as the problem is not at your level but in your parent, the registry of `.ml` that has one of its authoritative nameserver broken which is not good but should in practice only have as a consequence delays, not total breakage.

The trinity of public quad resolvers have no problem answering for your name:

```
$ dig @1.1.1.1 kesaralive.ml. A +short
195.20.48.31
$ dig @8.8.8.8 kesaralive.ml. A +short
195.20.48.31
$ dig @9.9.9.9 kesaralive.ml. A +short
195.20.48.31
```

So if "others" have trouble fetching it, the problem may also be on their side, but then we are far from being on topic here as this is not a website related question.

But I guess you get what you paid for. If you are serious about your online presence it may make sense to pay for a couple of dollars per year for a domain that will be hosted on a registry having all nameservers correctly configured and running all the time.

Comment: Yes Patrick, I agree with you. problem was not at my side. now the servers are working well and everything is looking normal. I'm still learning these things. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Issue the command `dig +trace kesaralive.ml`.

This may be a ns server misconfigured or offline problem.

At this time we can't do anything because it's Freenom's problem.

[command image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQN0K.png)

Comment: Thank you ouflak I had the doubt that the issue is at my side. now It's clear that nothing to do in my side. I have to wait till they solve the problem.